# memsql does not support temporary table or table variable?

Tags: temp-tables, table-variable, singlestore

Tried to create temp table in Memsql:

`Create temporary table ppl_in_grp as 
select pid from h_groupings where dt= '2014-10-05' and location = 'Seattle'`

Got this error: Feature 'TEMPORARY tables' is not supported by MemSQL.

Is there any equivalence I can use instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

temp tables are definitely on the roadmap. For now, with MemSQL 4 you can create a regular table and clean it up at the end of your session, or use subqueries.

Comment: Regular table is not really an option, because there will be multiple users run the same queries(different parameter values of course) at the same time, everyone needs their own temp table/table variable to continue with further compute....